# Cloudfront Redirects to Origin only when Static Content Signing is Enabled

Tags: magento2, static-content, cloudfront-cdn

I'm using AWS CloudFront with Magento 2.4.
When dev/static/sign is disabled, I have absolutely no issues with the CDN.
When dev/static/sign is enabled though, all static resources are redirected to the origin url.

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503322/cloudfront-distribution-with-custom-origin-redirects-request/22571467#22571467) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39298343/cloudfront-is-redirecting-to-our-website), with no success.

Has anyone encountered this?

Comment: I have the exactly same error, but didn't checked with unsigned to "no". Could it be related to the rewrite url of the version in the path?

Comment: @Mr.K I've got a feeling that it has to do with rewrites, but I'm not totally sure. I'll keep trying!

Comment: @Mr.K see the answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution to this issue.

My web root is `MagentoDir/pub`. In `pub/static/.htaccess`, the RewriteBase was set to `/pub/static`. When I changed that value to `/static/`, restarted apache and flushed Magento's caches, the problem was solved.

Comment: Than you! I need to check the similar fix for nginx config